# Suggest-Edit rights for 2k+?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could I optionally get my edit approved?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103270/could-i-optionally-get-my-edit-approved)

I read somewhere that it is impolite to edit questions and *"put words in other people's mouths"* which probably does make sense even if you sincerely believe that you are improving an answer, for example.

Since this is the case, I thought it would be nice if one could still *choose to* suggest edits at 2k+ which are directed at the author of the question rather than the community. After all, such an edit might change the meaning of the post and thus should be at the discretion of the original author.

Often people make good suggestions in comments, and I guess in some cases it might be difficult to express ideas that way, for example if they think an explicit code-example would be a nice addition.

What do people think about this? Could this perhaps have down-sides I didn't think of?

Comment: Don't believe everything you read somewhere.

Comment: In general, the way to suggest that the OP make an edit is to leave a comment. "Changes to code" comments should be brief, `and(can be written){this way};`  Using the Suggested Edits system in its existing form to do this won't work, because suggestions are directed to the community in general, not to the OP in particular.

Comment: @balpha: Haha, is there some official policy on this? I'll admit that i did not check the faqs...

Comment: Things can always be changed back, I don't think anyone should get worked up about edits to their posts.

Comment: @Renesis: Right now it's "change back if you disagree", i don't think it would hurt to offer "accept if you agree" as well. Further you do not even get properly notified of revisions so it might slip by unnoticed.

Comment: Are you familiar with comments? They're a great way to *suggest* something to the original poster, without actually putting words directly "in their mouth". I use them frequently.

Comment: Yup. I don't think such a feature is necessary. Expressing yourself in comments isn't all that difficult. They even support inline code formatting using backticks.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I know that in many cases comments work and i know that you can write code in comments. That is not the point, the suggestion is simply supposed to make some special cases possible and other cases more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Editing questions has nothing to do with putting words into someones mouth but with improving the entire questions by making it either more understandable, fixing errors or adding more information (if possible and necessary).

If someone feels offended by an edit or he thinks that the edit alters the original meaning too much, he can always revert the changes back to an older revision and/or post a question here on MSO to discuss that particular edit.

Comment: I was mostly referring to answers where edits are more intrusive than common correcting improvements, also as i noted in a comment edits which one might opose can easily be overlooked since you do not even get a notification.