# Question regarding edit vs. suggested edit

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

I know that at 2000 reputation, users receive the editing privilege, meaning they can edit a post directly without going through peer-reviewing.

However, users whose reputation is below 2000, can suggest edits, meaning that their review will go through an edit queue and will be peer-reviewed.

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Do edits by users with more than 2000 reputation provide any reputation? Is there any other incentive Stack Overflow provides for editing if they don't receive any reputation? (**This part is not answered in the duplicate target question.**)
2. Users can earn reputation through the suggested edit. Can a user with more than 2000 reputation still suggest edits? This question comes in my mind because it may be the case that the user did not receive any point through suggested edit (I know there is a cap of 1000 reputation point). That means if they did not receive any point through suggested edit but later obtained the edit privilege, they will not be able to claim that points.

Comment: _"Do edits of users with more than 2000 reputation provide any reputation point? Is there any other incentive Stack Overflow provides for editing if they don't receive any reputation point?"_ No reputation, badges maybe.

Comment: Possible (partial) duplicate of [Can I submit an edit for approval after earning 2k reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103270/can-i-submit-an-edit-for-approval-after-earning-2k-reputation)

Comment: Voting to reopen as while question 2 is answered in the duplicate, question 1 is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do edits of users with more than 2000 reputation provide any reputation point?

No, binding, privileged edits to posts do not provide any reputation.

> Is there any other incentive Stack Overflow provides for editing if they don't receive any reputation point?

Yes, there are badges for editing [80](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) and [500](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor) posts (both binding and suggested edits count towards it). There are also [badges for editing questions within 12 hours of answering them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/247/refiner), which are significantly easier to earn with binding edit privileges (if a suggested edit isn't approved within 12 hours, it won't count).

> Can a user with more than 2000 reputation, can still suggest edits?

No, all their edits to posts are binding. *Technically*, one could log out and suggest edits as an anonymous user, but they won't earn reputation for their edits, and this is a gray area with regard to policy: [prior discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231507/377214) have come to a consensus that once you gain a privilege, you are effectively trusted with it, and should take that into account.

> This question comes in my mind because it may be the case that the user did not receive any point through suggested edit (I know there is a cap of 1000 reputation point). That means if he did not receive any point through suggested edit but later obtained the edit privilege, he will not be able to claim that points.

Users can still suggest edits to tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts and earn reputation from those edits, provided they have less than 20,000 reputation (the minimum required to make binding tag wiki edits). Those reputation points will count toward the 1,000.

Comment: Re *"...less than 20,000 reputation"*: No, the limit is 5000 (when getting the approve tag wiki edits privilege).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Nope; that grants you the ability to *review* tag wiki suggested edits by others, but you can't bindingly edit tag wikis until you get 20,000 reputation. See the [relevant privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

Comment: I think the limit is 5,000 for ***earning*** *reputation points* from wiki edits. Between 5,000 and 20,000, edits can be suggested, but reputation points are not awarded. Or did they change it?