# Add ability to opt edits into review queue for users who have the edit post privilege for Peer-Review purposes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

Below 2000 rep, an edit to a post would go through screening, but having the privilege of having ones edits applied instantly loses the benefits of drawing attention to one's suggestions and makes it much more tedious to get a second opinion. This has led me personally to changing my mind about making certain improvements to posts like adding less specific tags or rephrasing the title of a question into an actual question for the sake of making it easier to find in the future. The reason I would opt out of doing that is in case I feel I might be misinterpreting something about the question and risk doing damage or because I'm uncertain of some guideline.

While I'd like to make a feature request to have the option to send one's edit through the edit suggestion queue (a checkbox to opt out of the privilege essentially), I think I see a downside to it in the form of clogging up the queue with suggestion of minuscule edits. Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I submit an edit for approval after earning 2k reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103270/can-i-submit-an-edit-for-approval-after-earning-2k-reputation)

Comment: Go ahead and edit - all of those (in the abstract) seem like reasonable ways of editing posts.

Comment: Reckless abandon it is! Thank you.

Comment: Reckless abandon is the way to go. Even above 2000 rep, the owner of the post gets a notification with a big "Reject" button -- they can rollback any (possible) garbage with a single click -- while the rest of the community can tell you exactly what you did wrong. It's cool -- editing is not permanent -- and this is a way for all of us to learn.